# How to calculate the silhouette coefficient?

Tags: data-mining, clustering, k-means, distance, k-nn

[image: Question]

[image: Formula for silhouette coefficient]

Calculate the silhouette coefficient of point Pi from the above image.

To apply the given formula, how to know which is a(i) and b(i)?

Answer (score 3):

a(i) : the average distance between 'i' and all other data within the same cluster ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)))

b(i) :  the lowest average distance of 'i' to all points in any other cluster, of which 'i' is not a member ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)))

So, from the question, a(i) will be 24 as point 'Pi' belongs to cluster A and b(i) will be 48 as it is the least average distance that 'Pi' has from any other cluster than A (to which it belongs).

So, as a(i) < b(i),  silhouette coefficient s(i) = 1 - 24/48 = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

$a_i = 24$

$b_i = (48 + 72)/2=60$

$1 - 24/60 =.6$